# Calculate working days in a month using Business_time gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am new in `ROR`, I want to write a function, to which I will pass `month` and it will return `total working days` (except Saturday and Sunday) of that particular month using `business_time` gem in rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (not tested):

```
first_day = Date.parse("September 30, 2012")
last_day = Date.parse("November 1, 2012")
first_day.business_days_until(last_day)
```

Comment: Sorry you have to start at the last day of the previous month otherwise the first day is not counted.

Comment: I did it using 
start_date = Date.parse("March 1, 2012");
end_date   = Date.parse("March 31,2012").at_beginning_of_month.next_month;
start_date.business_days_until(end_date);